# How to get Header text as required in CSV file in Windows Application?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, export-to-csv

I am using the following code to generate CSV file:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Stopwatch swra = new Stopwatch();
        swra.Start();
        string NewconnectionString = connectionString;
        StreamWriter CsvfileWriter = new StreamWriter(@"D:\testfile.csv");
        string sqlselectQuery = "select * from tblProperty";
        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();

        SqlConnection spContentConn = new SqlConnection(NewconnectionString);
        sqlcmd.Connection = spContentConn;
        sqlcmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
        sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlcmd.CommandText = sqlselectQuery;
        spContentConn.Open();
        using (spContentConn)
        {
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader())
            using (CsvfileWriter)
            {
                string columnNames = Enumerable.Range(0, sdr.FieldCount).Select(i => sdr.GetName(i)).ToString();


                CsvfileWriter.WriteLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));
                while (sdr.Read())
                    //based on your Table columns you can increase and decrese columns
                    CsvfileWriter.WriteLine(sdr[0].ToString() + "," + sdr[1].ToString() + "," + sdr[2].ToString() + "," + sdr[3].ToString() + "," + sdr[4].ToString() + "," + sdr[5].ToString() + "," + sdr[6].ToString() + "," + sdr[7].ToString() + "," + sdr[8].ToString() + "," + sdr[9].ToString() + ",");

            }
        }
        swra.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(swra.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
```

And in out put i get the data as below screen shot 
[image: this]
please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 IEnumerable<string> columnNames = Enumerable.Range(0, sdr.FieldCount)
                                             .Select(i => sdr.GetName(i));

 CsvfileWriter.WriteLine(string.Join(",", columnNames.ToArray()));
```